# How to open Google Map when I click on a button in android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Android Studio to make app that has some buttons. When I click on button call "find", it opens google map, but map is not displayed and is a blank map instead.

here my code

**android manifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
android:versionCode="1"

android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ssss"
    android:label="Active ATM"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="AcctiveATM"
        android:label="Active ATM" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".help"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ahmed.activeatm.help" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".map1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map1" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**main page.java**

```
 package com.example.ahmed.activeatm;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AcctiveATM extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Button button_sbm;
    private static Button button_sbm1;
    private static Button button_sbm2;
    private static DigitalClock digital;
    private static Button button_sbm3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acctive_atm);
        onButtonClickListener();
        onButtonClickListenerr();
        onClickButtonListener();
        setButton_sbm3ClickButtonListener();

    }

    public void onButtonClickListener(){
        button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AcctiveATM.this);
                        a_builder.setMessage("DO you want to close this app:")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                        alert.setTitle("Alert!!");
                        alert.show();
                    }
                }
        );

    }
    public void onButtonClickListenerr(){
        button_sbm1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button_sbm1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AcctiveATM.this);
                        a_builder.setMessage("this application enabels customers to find " +
                                "ATM machines near them using google maps and mobile GPS" +
                                "\n\n" +
                                "Devolop by ^_^:\n\n -alzergine\n-wd malik\n-alaa mohamed")
                                .setCancelable(false)

                                .setNegativeButton("Dissmise", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                        alert.setTitle("About...");
                        alert.show();
                    }
                }
        );

    }
    public void onClickButtonListener() {
        button_sbm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button_sbm2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.ahmed.activeatm.help");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void setButton_sbm3ClickButtonListener() {
        button_sbm3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button_sbm3.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       //Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment");

                  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),map1.class);

                         startActivity(i);
                       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_map1);
                      //  map1 a = new map1();
//a.setUpMapIfNeeded();

                    }
                }
        );




}}
```

**map.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context="com.example.ahmed.activeatm.map1"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**layout of main page**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".AcctiveATM"
android:background="#b8fff5">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:theme="@android:style/Animation.Dialog" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:theme="@android:style/Animation.Dialog"
    android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Help"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:theme="@android:style/Animation.Dialog"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="119dp" />

<DigitalClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#08041c"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Find"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/digitalClock"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/digitalClock"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/digitalClock" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Other location"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your map activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You do not have enough permissions](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) to use google maps. Check the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) permission

Comment: @user5419804 When using stackoverflow, when something has helped you find the problem, click the green v under the arrows.... this way, when another user googles the problem, and reads your question, he can see what answer to look into.... Also, use the Search function, with your problem keywords (like google maps, api, android blank screen), would also help you. And if an answer is a good answer, vote up (arrow up), or if its a bad answer, vote down (arrow down), to help sort the best answers first